# Skeleton CSS - Media Queries

Tags: css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

Using the Skeleton CSS boiler system, I'd like my `divs` to stretch to `100%` of the `width` when the viewing window is below `750px`. Right now, Skeleton gradually decreases the `div` sizes until around `400px`, then puts each element (`div.seven` and `div.five` on their own line with a `width` of `100%`). How can I have this happen sooner? The gallery (`div.five`) is shrunk too small to see/use at `600px`. Basically, when the `width` is <= `750px`, I want the `divs` to be "twelve columns".

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="seven columns">
        <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="five columns ">
        <ul class="bxslider">
            <li><img src="/img1.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="/img2.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="/img3.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
 /* Smaller than tablet */
 @media (max-width: 750px) {
    .seven { clear: both; width: 100%; }
    .five { clear: both; width: 100%; }   
 }
```

Comment: Please provide a Fiddle.